# Where should I put a function that is supposed to be run in the background - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following function :

```
func rocketsGo(){
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(8))

    self.rocket1.isHidden = true

    if randomNumber % 2 == 0 {
        if 0 == 0{
            self.rocket1.isHidden = false
            let xPosR = rocket1.frame.origin.x + 500

            let yPosR = rocket1.frame.origin.y

            let heightCharacterR = rocket1.frame.size.height
            let widthCharacterR = rocket1.frame.size.width

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.75, animations: {
                self.rocket1.frame = CGRect(x: xPosR, y: yPosR
                    , width: widthCharacterR, height: heightCharacterR)
            }) { (finished) in

            }
            self.rocket1.isHidden = true
            self.rocket1.frame = CGRect(x: xPosR - 500, y: yPosR, width: widthCharacterR, height: heightCharacterR)
```

Basically, what it does is it moves the rocket from one side of the screen to the other if the random number is even (so sometimes the rocket moves, sometimes it doesn't).

I want this function to be always run in the background since the whole idea behind my app is sometimes the rocket moves, sometimes it doesn't.
Where should I put the function so it can be run in the background?

The source code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var TheCharacter: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rocket1: UIImageView!

    func rocketsGo(){
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(8))

        self.rocket1.isHidden = true

        if randomNumber % 2 == 0 {
            if 0 == 0{
                self.rocket1.isHidden = false
                let xPosR = rocket1.frame.origin.x + 500

                let yPosR = rocket1.frame.origin.y

                let heightCharacterR = rocket1.frame.size.height
                let widthCharacterR = rocket1.frame.size.width

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.75, animations: {
                    self.rocket1.frame = CGRect(x: xPosR, y: yPosR
                    , width: widthCharacterR, height: heightCharacterR)
                }) { (finished) in

                }
                self.rocket1.isHidden = true
                self.rocket1.frame = CGRect(x: xPosR - 500, y: yPosR, width: widthCharacterR, height: heightCharacterR)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run your `rocketGo` function in the background. User interface updates must always be done on the main queue.

It sounds like you just want `rocketGo` to be called over and over. There are several ways to do this.

You can create a `Timer` with an appropriate interval and call `rocketGo` each time the timer triggers.

Or you can simply call `rocketGo` from the `finished` block of the view animation inside your `rocketGo` function. But then you need a way to trigger `rocketGo` when the random number of odd.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some playground code to do what you're asking:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

func printRandomInBackground() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let min : UInt32 = 1
        let max : UInt32 = 100
        let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(max - min) + min
        print("\(randomNumber)")
    }
}

printRandomInBackground()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Remember that if you want to update the UI, you'll need to switch to the main thread to do that.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {  
    // Update UI stuff here 
}
```

Comment: The question has been clarified. Please update or delete your answer.

Answer (score -2):

There is no reason that I can think of that you will ned a function to generate a random number but there is a way to create a variable in Swift that generates random numbers:

let randomNumber = NSUUID().uuidString

this will generate a random number all the time. And I would user this as a constant so that you can call it anytime you want. Hope this helps you and or anyone else.

Comment: Can you please give the full code?(I'm trying to do this in a game in Xcode)

Comment: The question has been clarified. Please update or delete your answer.